# if class equals something then add attrib to another div

Tags: jquery, class, attributes, equals

I am trying to write a function that will look for the class name "blocknew", and then add to the imgframe div's style attribute. Is this even possible?

Go from this:

```
<div class="block"><div class="imgframe" style="background:url(images/blah.jpg);"></div></div>
```

To this:

```
<div class="blocknew"><div class="imgframe" style="background:url(images/new.jpg), url(images/blah.jpg);"></div></div>
```

Function I have so far:

```
$(function () { $('.blocknew').children('.imgframe').attr("style", "background:url(images/new.png),"); });
```

Comment: Assigning all the styles will be tricky, which style elements do you need?

Comment: `$('.blocknew').children('.imgframe')` ?

Comment: Why `$('.blocknew').children('.imgframe')` is wrong?

Comment: okay `$('.blocknew').children('.imgframe')` would work but it would make an object for .blocknew before making another for .children when it can be done in one call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much discussion, this could be what OP means

```
$('.block .imgframe').each(function(){
    $(this).css('background', 'url(images/new.jpg),' + $(this).css('background'));
});
```

Comment: This works, however this overrides what is already in the html (background:url(images/blah.jpg). I have multiple div's with different image filenames (blah.jpg, blah2.jpg) and so on. So I need this function to only prepend the background:"url(images/new.jpg) in front of the background:url(images/blah.jpg) .. if that makes any sense.

Comment: added what i think you mean by prepending the background

Comment: i don't think i'm explaining myself very well, my apologies. The images/blah.jpg part is inline of the html. I need jquery to add to that without overriding the inline html.

Comment: ok. 12 kittens died because of confusion about what you wanted